# How to count the result in MYSQL in this scenario?

Tags: mysql, sql

The table structure is like that:

```
planID TinyInt(1)
userID INT(11)
isComplete TinyInt(1)
isQuit TinyInt(1)
```

So, first of all, I need to :

1. get the result from a specific userID
2. for each user, they may have join plan 1 (e.g. planID = 1), plan 2 or plan3 (can join again, unlimited time)
3. Count the isComplete times and isQuit times for all plan (1, 2, 3)

So, a user with  ID 1 , may join plan 3  3 times,  and 1 complete 2 quit, join plan 2 1 times , and 2 complete etc....

Somehow attempt

```
SELECT COUNT(`isComplete`) as total_complete, COUNT(`isQuit`) as total_quit FROM `user_plan` WHERE `userID` = 1 AND isComplete = 1 OR isQuit = 1 GROUP BY `planID`
```

but not the same as expected

If it is too complex I can query 3 times for each plan, Thanks for helping

**Updated 
Sample Input:**

```
planID      | userID    | isComplete    | isQuit
-------------------------------------------------------
1           | 1         | 0             | 1
1           | 1         | 1             | 0
1           | 1         | 0             | 0
```

Comment: Can you please provide sample input and output data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the query inspire by the Jithin Shaji 's answer, thanks for helping again.

```
SELECT  SUM(isComplete) as total_complete,
        SUM(isQuit) as total_quit,
        planID
FROM    user_plan
WHERE   userID = 31 
GROUP   BY planID
```

Answer (score 2):

If the case was in SQL Server, it wold have been like this. (If is read the question correct)

```
SELECT  userID,
        SUM(isComplete) as total_complete, 
        SUM(isQuit) as total_quit 
FROM    user_plan
WHERE   userID = 1 
AND     isComplete = 1 
GROUP   BY userID
```

Comment: Add userID in the SELECT